# File size is always 0 in the SharedWithMe items in OneDrive Business

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am retrieving the list of files and folders that are "Shared With Me" in my OneDrive Business account. I am primarily using Microsoft Graph SDK to fetch the results as shown below:

```
var response = await client.Me.Drive.SharedWithMe().Request().GetAsync();
```

However, file size property in the response is always returned as 0. I have verified the size property of DriveItem as well as RemoteItem of the response. There is no limitation mentioned anywhere in the specs, but this value is always returned as 0.

The normal HTTP Get call to API as mentioned [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/shared_with_me.htm) also returns the file size as 0. I needed to know how can I retrieve the file size of Shared With Me items.

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of the shared with me API for OneDrive for Business. I will get the docs updated to reflect this limitation. That being said, we are working to remove this limitation. Stay tuned.

Comment: We are having the same issue. Any updates on this? It's still returned as 0. Thanks.